# PHPExcel - how to design excel - change colors, merge rows?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

HI I am using PHPExcel I need to design excel with some color and merge row and column,

What I have created is

```
include ('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("My Sheet");

$rowCount = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Title");

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, 'test val1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'test val2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('c'.$rowCount, 'test val3');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('uploadedimage/Report/some_excel_file.xlsx');
```

this code produce an excel sheet but I need to have an excel sheet with huge data and  formatting

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Merging cells:**
`$objPHPExcel->mergeCells("D1:N1");`

**Setting color:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
        )
    )
);
```